# Unable to dowload file from ftp with maven-antrun-plugin (0 files retrieved)

Tags: maven, ftp, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using maven-antrun-plugin in order to download a dump from a FTP.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ftp</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <ftp action="get" 
                                 server="myserver" 
                                 remotedir="/remotedir/"
                                 userid="anonymous" 
                                 password="anonymous" 
                                 depends="yes" 
                                 verbose="yes">
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}">
                                    <include name="**/*.*" />
                                </fileset>
                            </ftp>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The plugin seems to work but it doesn't download my dump ("*0 files retrieved*").

```
> main:
>       [ftp] Opening FTP connection to myserver
>       [ftp] connected
>       [ftp] logging in to FTP server
>       [ftp] login succeeded
>       [ftp] changing the remote directory to /remotedir/
>       [ftp] getting files fileset: Setup scanner in dir /myproject/target with patternSet{ includes: [**/*.*] excludes: [] }
>       [ftp] 0 files retrieved
>       [ftp] disconnecting
```

I'm able to download this dump with FileZilla on myserver/remotedir/ (in an anonymous way). When I purposely try a wrong remotedir it warns me correctly ("*550 Failed to change directory.*") so I guess there is no connection problem.

Comment: have you tried setting passive to yes?

Comment: @pvg Oh ! I just saw your comment. You're right, it worked with **passive attribute to "yes"**. I found it at same time while reading Ant manual. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it works! Referring to [Ant manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html), I'm using **passive** attribute in Ant FTP Task.

> If you can connect but not upload or download, try setting the passive attribute to true to use the existing (open) channel, instead of having the server try to set up a new connection.

And here's the thing in pom.xml :

```
<target>
    <ftp action="get" 
     server="myserver" 
     remotedir="/remotedir"
     userid="anonymous" 
     password="anonymous" 
     verbose="yes"
     passive="yes">

        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```